# Thymeleaf - Parsing external CSS file? Expressions, variables etc

Tags: css, spring, thymeleaf

There does not seem to be any concrete answers from what I could find, although I'm more inclined to say this is not possible.

However, is it possible to use Thmymeleaf expressions within an external CSS file? For example, if I have **main.css** and it contains:

```
body {
    font-size: [[${fooBean.isLarge ? '22px;' : '16px;' }]];
}

.header {
    margin-top:
    background: url{[[${fooBean.isMain ? '/img/blue.jpg' : '/img/red.jpg' }]]}
                    no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Is this possible at all using Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thymeleaf 3 introduced new template modes](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#template-modes).  One of them is CSS,  [you can see an example of one here](https://github.com/jmiguelsamper/thymeleaf3-template-modes-example/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/css/main.css).  You'd have to set up all the spring stuff/controllers, but you should be able to use them like normal (adding your fooBean to the model).

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for.